# Sharing class across unit, intergration and funcational tests

Tags: grails

I have a TestUtils class with a bunch of static methods I want to share across my unit, integration and functional tests in my grails project.

How do I do this?

I was thinking of adding it to `src/groovy` but then it means test code is in the middle of source code - not good.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can use plugins, add it in a plugin and include plugin as test dependency

Comment: just use `src/groovy` and put it into a explicit `test` package so it is clear that his is no production code. If you don't want the package in the war you can use eventCreateWarStart = { name, stagingDir -> ..} in _Events.groovy to remove it before packaging.